# Rails - Sqlite not showing records shown in application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I recently tried to modify the sqlite database for my rails app, and I noticed that the database itself was only showing records from 1 week ago.  Even though when I look at the application running it is showing me current records of today.  I confirmed that the server was running out of the directory I expected it to be, and that database.yml was pointing to db/development.sqlite3

Is there some possibility that rails was saving that all in some other file, or in memory?  I do not know if my server was compromised but I am baffled at how the web application shows me records that are not in my database.

EDIT:  I did open the database via SFTP on the 9th to toggle an administrator permission.  I noticed that after I did that, the permissions on the database file were rw-r--r-- ..... But if I had messed up the permissions, then the entire site would not have been able to write and read from the database.

Comment: First of all in what environment your application is running? In which one you are testing? db/developemnt.sqlite3 seems to point to development database. Rails has by default 3 different enviroments(development, test, production).

The second thing is: could you show how you access this sqlite database?

Comment: we have always just used the development.sqlite3 database